# Reading data and live updating animation in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am receiving data (16 bytes/4 floats every 100us) input on my computer through COM3 port and taking the most recent input to update my pygame (that is running at 60fps).I wrote code using asyncio to run the pygame and the reading data in parallel. It seems that the data is getting scrambled and then causing my pygame to exit out after a little bit, because for some reason the data is getting read as a really large number (when it shouldn't be). I copied the important parts of my code below.

My idea was to have the data read as fast as it can(even if the data is just going into a void) and silently run in the background. At the same time the animation stuff will be running and when I need to update for the next frame, it will take the data at that moment.

Is this right? Should I be using asyncio or is there a better one to use?

```
# reading port function
async def readport(s):
        #read incoming data coming in every 100us
        #data comes in as 4 floats and the last float is constant used to check the data
        res=s.read(16)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        #parse data
        ypos=struct.unpack('!f',res[3::-1])[0]
        xpos=struct.unpack('!f',res[7:3:-1])[0]
        yamp=struct.unpack('!f',res[11:7:-1])[0]
        xamp=struct.unpack('!f',res[15:11:-1])[0]
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        if xamp != 5.0:
            print('values', [xpos,ypos,xamp,yamp])
            # print('something wrong')
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        return xpos, ypos

async def animate(running,robot, xp, yp):
    #show on screen 
    global TIME_STEP
    global simtime
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            # The user closed the window or pressed escape
            running = False
            return running
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # Draw the world
    for body in world.bodies:
        for fixture in body.fixtures:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            fixture.shape.draw(body, fixture)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
    #update robot position from the data
    robot.position = b2Vec2(xp,yp+12)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

    world.Step(TIME_STEP, 10, 10)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    simtime = simtime + TIME_STEP
    print(simtime)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # Flip the screen and try to keep at the target FPS
    pygame.display.flip()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    clock.tick(TARGET_FPS)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return running

async def main(bps,xpos,ypos,robot, running):
    with serial.Serial('COM3',baudrate=bps,bytesize=8, timeout=None, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=False) as s:
        print('Opened',s.name)
        while running:
            (xpos, ypos), running = await asyncio.gather(readport(s), animate(running,robot,xpos,ypos))
    pygame.quit()
    print('Done!')
```

I tried switching over to threading and correcting the struct.unpack so that I don't have to iterate backwards. However, I still have the problem of the messaging scrambling. Usually, it runs for a few seconds and then the message becomes scrambled. The updated code is below.

```
class Pipeline:
    """
    Class to allow a single element pipeline between producer and consumer.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 0
        self.producer_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.consumer_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.consumer_lock.acquire()

    def get_message(self, name):
        self.consumer_lock.acquire()
        message = self.message
        self.producer_lock.release()
        return message

    def set_message(self, message, name):
        self.producer_lock.acquire()
        self.message = message
        self.consumer_lock.release()

    # reading port function
    def readport(pipeline):
    #read incoming data coming in every 100us
    with serial.Serial('COM3',baudrate=3000000,bytesize=8, timeout=None, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=False) as s:
        print('Opened',s.name)
        while True:
            res=s.read(16)
            #parse data
            ypos=struct.unpack('f',res[0:4])[0]
            xpos=struct.unpack('f',res[4:8])[0]
            yamp=struct.unpack('f',res[8:12])[0]
            xamp=struct.unpack('f',res[12:16])[0]
            #might need to add a flag every 60 fps to set the pipline
            pipeline.set_message([xpos,ypos], "Data")
            if xamp != 5.0:
                print('values', [xpos,ypos,xamp,yamp])
                break
                # print('something wrong')

    def animation(pipline):
    running = True
    simtime = 0
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                # The user closed the window or pressed escape
                running = False
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255, 255))
        # Draw the world
        for body in world.bodies:
            for fixture in body.fixtures:
                fixture.shape.draw(body, fixture)
        #update robot position from the data
        xpos, ypos = pipline.get_message('Robot')
        robot1.position = b2Vec2(xpos,ypos+12)
        world.Step(TIME_STEP, 10, 10)
        simtime = simtime + TIME_STEP
        print(simtime)
        # Flip the screen and try to keep at the target FPS
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(TARGET_FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    print('Done!')


    # --- main game loop ---

    pipline = Pipeline()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(readport, pipline)
        executor.submit(animation,pipline)
```

Comment: Reading from a serial port can sometimes result in partial reads. Meaning that you might not always get the full 16 bytes you're expecting. This can cause data misalignment and might be the reason you're seeing unexpected large values. Also since you're reading and writing to shared variables (xpos and ypos), there's a potential for race conditions. You should consider using a lock or other synchronization mechanism to ensure that the data is read/written atomically.

Comment: @Joaquin I believe Python will retry short reads until it fills the buffer or EOF is reached.  In any case `struct` would raise an exception if the buffer doesn't contain 4 bytes.

Comment: I'd suggest just calling `struct.unpack` once with the correct byte order specified rather than manually byte flipping.  It'd be much easier to read, portable, and should be faster.  That said you're likely better using threads for that as pySerial doesn't seem to provide an async API.  writing a tuple containing the fields into a global variable would be thread safe thanks to the global interpreter lock.